# How can a C# Universal Windows Application accept command-line arguments (args)

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments, win-universal-app, args

In an application that is for Windows Desktops, there is a way to accept command-line arguments through Windows Explorer/File Explorer. (args)

In Windows Phone, there is a Files/File Explorer app as well. How can I accept command-line arguments from the Files/File Explorer app? Is it possible?

Note: I am programming for Universal Windows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Universal Windows Applications are not WPF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use at least 2 ways to activate your Universal app :

- Uri activation. Your app will launch as soon as you launch an Uri with your registered protocol ( Press [Windows + R] type "[bingmaps:?q=restaurant&where=Paris](http://bingmaps:?q=restaurant&where=Paris)")

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh779670(v=win.10).aspx

- File association. Your app will be launched when an associated file is launched

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh779669(v=win.10).aspx